# printing the total value only one time without iteration

Tags: java

I want to print the statement `System.out.println(sb.append(ss));`

Only the last time I tried to take it out of the `for` loop but the result is wrong.

```
 public static String constatmentvertBinaryStringToString(String string) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    String ss = null;

    //for each character
    for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j += 8) {
        int idx = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        //for each bit in reverse
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (chars[i + j] == '1') {
                sum += 1 << idx;
            }
            idx++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum); //debug
        int div = sum / 4;
        System.out.println(div);
        System.out.println((char) div);
        int rem = sum % 4;
        System.out.println(rem);
        ss = (char) div + "" + rem;
        System.out.println(sb.append(ss));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code. Also, I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have output that is iterated by for loop but i want the statement is not iterated , just print only last time

Comment: Then take the statement out of the loop.

Comment: Move the print statement outside of the loop, then.

Comment: i do it but the result is not correct

Comment: 323130"0&2((not requierd  )
147
36
$
3
323130"0&2$3((not requierd  )
156
39
'
0
323130"0&2$3'0((not requierd  )
144
36
$
0
323130"0&2$3'0$0((not requierd  )
146
36
$
2
323130"0&2$3'0$0$2(not requierd  )
154
38
&
2
323130"0&2$3'0$0$2&2(i want this line to be printed)

Answer (score 0):

Put System.out.println(sb.append(ss)); out of the loop:

```
public static String constatment vertBinaryStringToString(String string){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
   String ss=null;
   //for each character
   for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j+=8) {
      int idx = 0;
      int sum =0;
      //for each bit in reverse
      for (int i = 7; i>= 0; i--) {
         if (chars[i+j] == '1') {
            sum += 1 << idx;
      }
      idx++;
   }            
   System.out.println(sum); //debug
   int div=sum/4;
   System.out.println(div);
   System.out.println((char)div);
   int rem=sum%4;
   System.out.println(rem);
   ss=(char)div+""+rem;   
   } 
   System.out.println(sb.append(ss));
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `System.out.println(sb.append(ss));` contains a call to `sb.append(ss));` taking the statement out of the `for` loop will have a different result than the one expected.

You should keep `sb.append(ss);` inside the loop and add `System.out.println(sb)` outside the loop.

```
public static String constatmentvertBinaryStringToString(String string) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    String ss = null;

    //for each character
    for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j += 8) {
        int idx = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        //for each bit in reverse
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (chars[i + j] == '1') {
                sum += 1 << idx;
            }
            idx++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum); //debug
        int div = sum / 4;
        System.out.println(div);
        System.out.println((char) div);
        int rem = sum % 4;
        System.out.println(rem);
        ss = (char) div + "" + rem;
        sb.append(ss);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```